# Heroku deployment failing on github request

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy an old application to heroku but I keep getting the following error:

```
remote:        Cached directories were not restored due to a change in     version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote:        Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:
remote: -----    Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! Error while executing:
remote:        npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/bessdsv/bower-installer.git
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
remote:        npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```